# Questions which include answers within the Question

Tags: exam, exercises, answers

I want to create Questions wherein each will include a series of fill in the blanks.

I want to display a worksheet which has an answer line in place of the answers. 
And then a worksheet where the answers are included over the answer line. 
And finally all the answers at the end.

What I'm aiming for:

Question worksheet with fill in the blanks.
[image: Questions]

Question worksheet with blanks filled in
[image: Questions with Answers included]

Answers only

[image]

I've looked at some packages like exercise, and exam but I don't think I can quite manipulate them to get what I'm after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with a solution that does what I need. 
This might be helpful for anyone else. 
If anyone has other suggestions I'd be grateful as I'm just hacking around.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{tasks}

% Set the Show Answers Boolean
\newboolean{showAns}
\setboolean{showAns}{false}
\newcommand{\showAns}{\setboolean{showAns}{true}}

% The length of the Answer line
\newlength{\answerlength}
\newcommand{\anslen}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{#1}}

% ans command that indicates space for an answer or shows the answer in red
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{showAns}}%
        {\textcolor{red}{\underline{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}}}%
        {\underline{\hspace{\answerlength}}}}%

% Formatting how multiple choices Questions are formated.
\settasks{counter-format={tsk[A].}}


% Some commands for the Exercise Question package
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{\Large\protect\textcircled{\small\bfseries\arabic{Question}}\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{} %no header
\renewcommand{\QuestionBefore}{3ex} %Space above each Q
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{8pt} % Indent after Q number


% To create the list of answers with tocloft... 
\newcommand{\listanswername}{Answers}
\newlistof[Question]{answer}{Answers}{\listanswername}

% Creates a TOC for Answers
\newcounter{prevQ}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\refstepcounter{answer}%
\ans{#1}%
\ifnum\theQuestion=\theprevQ%
        \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{}#1}% don't include the Q number
        \else%
        \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theQuestion}#1}%
        \setcounter{prevQ}{\value{Question}}%
        \fi%
        }%


%tocloft formatting listofanswers
\renewcommand{\cftAnswerstitlefont}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand{\cftanswerdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\cftpagenumbersoff{answer} 
\addtolength{\cftanswernumwidth}{10pt}


\begin{document}

\showAns

\begin{Exercise}
\Question $1+2$ is (\answer{C})
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task 1
\task 2
\task 3
\task 4
\end{tasks}

\Question $2+3=$~\answer{$5$}

\Question A question might have multiple places for the answer. The first answer is \answer{This is the answer}. The second answer is \answer{this is the other answer}.

\end{Exercise}
%Now just the answers

\listofanswer


\end{document}
```

Here's what the code produces without `\showAns`
[image: Question with spaces]

with `\showAns`
[image: Question with Answers]

And the tocloft package produces this for `\listofanswer`

[image: answers only]